# SendGrid generated unsubscribe links are pointing to a non-existent sub-domain of my website. How do I fix it to use a SendGrid hosted unsub page?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am using SendGrid For transactional email with dynamic templates. I have followed all the directions I can find about setting up unsubscribe groups but when I send an email with the API the link generated by SendGrid for the unsubscribe is pointing to a sub-domain of my domain that does not exist.

It feels like I've missed something in the setup that requires DNS configuration but I can't find any documentation to that effect.

I have done the following things that I found documentation for:

- Added a unsubscribe module to my template
- Created an unsubscribe group
- Added the unsubscribe group id to the request

My expectation:

I was expecting the link generated by SendGrid to point at an unsubscribe page hosted by SendGrid.

The result is a broken link to a sub-domain on my domain that does not exist:

https://url7406.bcwilliams.dev/asm/unsubscribe/?user_id=29782719&data=fNnFEjHK2UDse2Lo_9RLfZlRHlcIh4Q2GsNvlJ2JWj9oMDAwdTAwMMbCZIQ9Y75_9TaiiUMMJ1k_RTDSiUCFrqH4YGliaLd-tTKfrMOMFLxk3TuyWA17V8HEEG6gZLlYrFV0tvlhdtS7XyuDVug5hLlosiFOSOnboFB9FuAkayrbUWMooxxnToJEYhsfNJem-i5n1jQtQP5Y4_z4meeYG6x_J6w0uoec-qgTNoehQ6QUFQUkEqfQfUbHwY8AjuxvURc6SpBpkoEqCGeU-Nj8wUwXkrCNYHjyMIZrpGj-cF-qLVaix7d_NeTIysSKe9T_atoKh7cAZ8bOjzsMMz4zvrjsDcV5iJjh9ryysmaHt7V6JSpUlzEry50psuZ09iUhDEmA5BSOcP5ertH-_mEOTbfLmS5daLkGdLPyUFyR_UTKlOISAMtMopoQ8CE1p9fajZ5JTquV-OudPEp_pBn0lkxz4oHLLO97c8vZgx1Qsd5YFnQwCGd_lbW_-qv6dkK-a5fwAR_fQ0pGYzbC0jDC-L-MxUDSQMcN_6MKkW6as3i2e-Rd8h_1jLHBpjpQgkUxch7H1J6Ih3E=

Answer (score 0):

I created my own issue!

In the end it turned out that the link being generated was broken because of a misconfiguration in link branding settings.

If anyone else comes across an issue where the generated link is broken and pointing to your own domain check your link branding settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).